# Frobenius norm of an orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I've tried multiplying this out to see if there's a pattern. I originally thought that the orthogonal projector was made up of orthonormal basis because the equation for it is sigma qiqi*, but that doesn't work.

I've also tried using root(trace(PP*)) = root (trace(P)) , but I can't see a pattern there that helps me either.

I have a feeling that this should be one (some intuition). How should I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What are the $q_i$? Tried multiplying *what* out? Projections aren't "made up" of bases. You can express *any* transformation in terms of a basis, but they don't rely on bases to exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But for sure, for a projection $P$ (i.e. self-adjoint idempotent), we have $\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(P^*P)}=\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(PP^*)}=\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(P)}=\sqrt{\mbox{rank}(P)}$. And that's $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|Q_{ij}|^2}$ for any matrix $Q$ representing $P$  in an orthonormal basis, i.e. the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Orthogonal projectors are self-adjoint, meaning $P^\ast =P$.

Compute $tr(PP^\ast)=tr(P^2)=\_\_\_\_$

---

(This is probably closer to the question you were asking, and I just didn't see it before.)

Hint 2: If you listed all the components of $P$ out in a row vector $q$ with entries $q_i$, then $tr(PP^\ast)$ is indeed $qq^\ast$. To see this, you just need to write down what the diagonal entries of $PP^\ast$ are, and then sum them together.